# How to make my code more OOP?

Tags: java

Hi I've finished my code but I want to make it shorter and more OOP. Can anyone help me out?

The question The cost to become a member of a fitness center is as follows:

a. the Senior citizens discount is 30%;
b. if the membership is bought and paid for 12 or more months in advance, the discount is 15%;
c. if more than 5 personal training sessions are purchased, the discount on each session is 20%.

Write a menu driven program that determines the cost of a new membership. Your program must contain a method that displays the general information about the fitness center and its charges, a method to get all the necessary information to determine the membership cost, and a method to determine the membership cost.

Use appropriate parameters to pass information in and out of a method.

```java
package com.diit;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner Object
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        information();
        input();
        price();
    }

    public static void information() {
        System.out.println("\n\nWelcome to Fitness Centre!");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("If you are a senior citizen, then you are eligible for a\ndiscount of 30% of the regular membership price");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("If you buy membership for twelve months and pay today, the discount is 15%");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("If you purchased more than 5 personal training sessions\n,the discount of each session is 20%");
        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------\n");
    }

    public static void input() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please fill in your information");
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + name + "to our Fitness Centre!");
    }

    public static void price() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declarations
        int age, twelve = 0, sessions = 0;
        double total, price, price2, months = 0, months2;

        System.out.println("Please enter your age: ");
        age = in.nextInt();

        if (age >= 0 && age <= 60) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to pay for you membership 12 months or more in advance? (1 for YES, 2 for NO");
            twelve = in.nextInt();

            if (twelve == 2) {
                System.out.println("How many months do you want to pay for?");
                System.out.println("The original price per month is RM140");
                months = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("How many training sessions do you want to purchase (0-10)");
                System.out.println("The original price per sessions is RM85");
                sessions = in.nextInt();

                if (sessions > 5) {
                    price = 68;
                    price2 = price * sessions;
                    months2 = months * 140;
                    total = months2 + price2;
                    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + total);
                }

                if (sessions < 5 && sessions >= 0) {
                    price = 85;
                    price2 = price * sessions;
                    months2 = months * 140;
                    total = months2 + price2;
                    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + total);
                }

            } else if (twelve == 1) {
                System.out.println("How many months do you want to pay for?");
                System.out.println("The original price per month is RM140");
                months = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("How many training sessions do you want to purchase (0-10)");
                System.out.println("The original price per sessions is RM85");
                sessions = in.nextInt();


                if (sessions > 5) {
                    price = 68;
                    price2 = price * sessions;
                    months2 = months * 119;
                    total = months2 + price2;
                    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + total);
                }
                if (sessions < 5 && sessions >= 0) {
                    price = 85;
                    price2 = price * sessions;
                    months2 = months * 119;
                    total = months2 + price2;
                    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + total);
                }
            }
        }
            else if (age >= 60) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You are entitled to a 30% discount.");
            System.out.println("Do you want to pay for you membership 12 months or more in advance? (1 for YES, 2 for NO");
            twelve = in.nextInt();

            if (twelve == 2) {
                System.out.println("How many months do you want to pay for?");
                System.out.println("The original price per month is RM140");
                months = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("How many training sessions do you want to purchase (0-10)");
                System.out.println("The original price per sessions is RM85");
                sessions = in.nextInt();

                if (sessions > 5) {
                    price = 68;
                    price2 = price * sessions;
                    months2 = months * 98;
                    total = months2 + price2;
                    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + total);
                }

                if (sessions < 5 && sessions >= 0) {
                    price = 85;
                    price2 = price * sessions;
                    months2 = months * 98;
                    total = months2 + price2;
                    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + total);
                }
                if (sessions < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid!");
                }
            }
            if (twelve == 1) {
                System.out.println("How many months do you want to pay for?");
                System.out.println("The original price per month is RM140");
                months = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("How many training sessions do you want to purchase (0-10)");
                System.out.println("The original price per sessions is RM85");
                sessions = in.nextInt();

                if (sessions > 5) {
                    price = 68;
                    price2 = price * sessions;
                    months2 = months * 83.3;
                    total = months2 + price2;
                    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + total);
                }
                if (sessions < 5 && sessions >= 0) {
                    price = 85;
                    price2 = price * sessions;
                    months2 = months * 83.3;
                    total = months2 + price2;
                    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + total);
                }

                if (sessions < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do the gym discounts stack?

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea.  A Java method is an encapsulation of code to produce one output.

I reworked your code and created 10 methods, not including the main method.  Each method does one thing.

I removed all but one instance of `Scanner`.  It's not a good idea to have more than one `System.in` `Scanner`.  I pass that `Scanner` instance to all the methods that read from the console.

Method names should be a verb-noun combination, like `printInformation` or `processMember`.

I created two methods with the same name, `calculateTotal`.  Since the two methods have different input parameter signatures, there's no confusion on the compiler's part.  Hopefully, you'll see the difference.

I tested your code a few times, but check my work to make sure I got the discount calculations correct.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner Object
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        new Question4().processMember(in);
        in.close();
    }
    
    public void processMember(Scanner in) {
        printInformation();
        double total = processInformation(in);
        String formattedTotal = String.format("%,.2f", total);
        System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + formattedTotal);
    }

    private void printInformation() {
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to Fitness Centre!\n");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("If you are a senior citizen, then you are "
                + "eligible for a\ndiscount of 30% of the regular "
                + "membership price");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("If you buy a membership for twelve months "
                + "or more and pay today, the discount is 15%");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("If you purchased more than 5 personal training "
                + "sessions,\nthe discount of each session is 20%\n");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------\n");
    }

    private double processInformation(Scanner in) {
        readName(in);
        int age = readAge(in);
        boolean advance = readAdvance(in);
        int months = readMonths(in, advance);
        int sessions = readSessions(in);
        return calculateTotal(age, advance, months, sessions);
    }
    
    private void readName(Scanner in) {
        System.out.println("Please fill in your information");
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + name + " to our Fitness Centre!");
    }

    private int readAge(Scanner in) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your age: ");
        int age = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        
        if (age >= 60) {
             System.out.println("Congratulations! You are entitled "
                    + "to a 30% discount.");
        }
        
        return age;
    }

    private boolean readAdvance(Scanner in) {
        System.out.print("Do you want to pay for you membership 12 months "
                + "or more in advance? (Y for YES, N for NO) ");
        String response = in.nextLine();
        boolean advance = Character.toLowerCase(response.charAt(0)) == 'y';
        
        return advance;
    }

    private int readMonths(Scanner in, boolean advance) {
        int months;
        do {
            System.out.println("How many months do you want to pay for?");
            System.out.println("The original price per month is RM140");
            months = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
        } while (months < 0 || (advance && months < 12));
        return months;
    }

    private int readSessions(Scanner in) {
        int sessions;
        do {
            System.out.println("How many training sessions do you "
                    + "want to purchase (0-10)");
            System.out.println("The original price per sessions is RM85");
            sessions = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
        } while (sessions < 0 || sessions > 10);
        
        return sessions;
    }
    
    private double calculateTotal(int age, boolean advance, 
            int months, int sessions) {
        double total;
        
        if (age >= 0 && age < 60) {
            if (advance) {
                total = calculateTotal(sessions, 85, months, 140, 15);
            } else {
                total = calculateTotal(sessions, 85, months, 140, 0);
            }
        } else {     
             total = calculateTotal(sessions, 85, months, 140, 30);   
        }
        
        return total;
    }
    
    private double calculateTotal(int sessions, int sessionsPrice, 
            int months, int membershipPrice, int discount) {
          if (sessions < 5 && sessions >= 0) {
              double sessionsTotal = sessionsPrice * sessions;
              double membershipTotal = membershipPrice * months * 
                      (1.0 - discount * 0.01);
              return sessionsTotal + membershipTotal;
          } else {
              double sessionsTotal = sessionsPrice * sessions * 0.8;
              double membershipTotal = membershipPrice * months * 
                      (1.0 - discount * 0.01);
              return sessionsTotal + membershipTotal;
          }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi sir what does this line of code mean? Sorry I am a beginner 

String formattedTotal = String.format("%,.2f", total);

Comment: Java has a complete [API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) that describes in detail all of the classes and methods that make up the Java platform. The format method of String in this case formats a double into a String with a decimal point and comma every three digits.

Comment: @Aaron: as a complete beginner it might be a good idea to go your way through the Java Tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

One thing important to me is to separate the presentation part (input and display) with your business rules. It will be easier to test (and better, you can even do TDD ;) ).
I wrote this, it is not complete, all of your business rules are not covered, but I think you can get the idea : gather all the info you need from the UI to compute the price, and then call the Pricer.

First, the input reader (inspired by the Gilbert's answer) :

```
public class InputReader {

    private int age = 0;
    private int months = 0;
    private int sessions = 0;

    private final Scanner scanner;

    public InputReader(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    private Order processMember() {
        informationMessage();
        welcome();
        readAge();
        readMonths();
        readSessions();
        return new Order(age, months, sessions);
    }

    private void informationMessage() {
        outWithNewLine("");
        outWithNewLine("");
        outWithNewLine("Welcome to Fitness Centre!");
        outSeparator();
        outWithNewLine("If you are a senior citizen, then you are eligible for a");
        outWithNewLine("discount of 30% of the regular membership price");
        outSeparator();
        outWithNewLine("If you buy membership for twelve months and pay today, the discount is 15%");
        outSeparator();
        outWithNewLine("If you purchased more than 5 personal training sessions");
        outWithNewLine(",the discount of each session is 20%");
        outSeparator();
    }

    private void welcome() {
        outWithNewLine("Please fill in your information");
        out("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        outWithNewLine("Welcome " + name + " to our Fitness Centre!");
    }

    private void readAge() {
        outWithNewLine("Please enter your age: ");
        age = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        if (age >= 60) {
            outWithNewLine("Congratulations! You are entitled to a 30% discount.");
        }
    }

    private void readMonths() {
        while (months <= 0) {
            outWithNewLine("How many months do you want to pay for?");
            outWithNewLine("The original price per month is RM140");
            months = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }

    private void readSessions() {
        while(sessions <= 0 || sessions > 10) {
            outWithNewLine("How many training sessions do you want to purchase (0-10)");
            outWithNewLine("The original price per sessions is RM85");
            sessions = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
    
    private void outWithNewLine(String content) {
        System.out.println(content);
    }

    private void out(String content) {
        System.out.print(content);
    }

    private void outSeparator() {
        outWithNewLine("--------------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

Then, a Pricer that computes the price :

```
public class Pricer {
    private static final BigDecimal ONE_SESSION_PRICE = BigDecimal.valueOf(85L);
    private static final BigDecimal MEMBERSHIP_FOR_ONE_MONTH = BigDecimal.valueOf(140L);
    private static final BigDecimal SESSION_DISCOUNT = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.15d);
    private static final BigDecimal SENIOR_DISCOUNT = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.3);

    private final int age;
    private final BigDecimal nbMonthsToPay;
    private final BigDecimal nbSession;
    
    public Pricer(Order order) {
        this.age = order.age;
        this.nbMonthsToPay = new BigDecimal(order.months);
        this.nbSession = new BigDecimal(order.sessions);
    }

    public String membershipAmount() {
        BigDecimal membershipAmount = computeMembershipPrice();
        BigDecimal sessionAmount = computeSessionPrice();
        return membershipAmount.add(sessionAmount).toString();
    }

    private BigDecimal computeSessionPrice() {
        BigDecimal sessionAmount = ONE_SESSION_PRICE.multiply(nbSession);
        if (nbSession.intValue() >= 6) {
            return sessionAmount.subtract(sessionAmount.multiply(SESSION_DISCOUNT));
        }
        return sessionAmount;
    }

    private BigDecimal computeMembershipPrice() {
        BigDecimal membership = MEMBERSHIP_FOR_ONE_MONTH.multiply(nbMonthsToPay);
        if (age >= 60) {
            return membership.subtract(membership.multiply(SENIOR_DISCOUNT));
        }
        return membership;
    }
}
```

The Order (I put public fields because the class is immutabe) :

```
public class Order {
    public final int age;
    public final int months;
    public final int sessions;

    public Order(int age, int months, int sessions) {
        this.age = age;
        this.months = months;
        this.sessions = sessions;
    }
}
```

The main method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Order order = new InputReader(scanner).processMember();
    String membershipAmount = new Pricer(order).membershipAmount();
    System.out.println("Your total price in MYR is RM" + membershipAmount);
    scanner.close();
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think your answer is of any use for the Questioner. It does not explain the concept you want to show and how your code snipped fits into that concept.

Comment: Hello, sad to hear that, but I am ready to improve my answer. What do you think I can add to make it better ? A call to the pricer ?

Comment: The Questioner provided a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) so you should do the same, maybe not completely covering all the original code but enough to show your, that the output of your  code is the same as the original and  the TO can play with it...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right, I see what you mean. I have improved my answer and I think it's more useful now.